# Animate.css website color gradient animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

sorry if this is a bit out of place on Stack Overflow, but I was on the [Animate.css website](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) by Daniel Eden and noticed the super awesome CSS color animation on the heading and button which has a slight gradient to it and the text highlight color which also changes.

Does anyone know if this is a library available to everyone or if it's something Daniel Eden built himself? (And if so, a way to replicate it?)

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could've just looked at his stylesheet. He's using a [hue shift filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#hue-rotate()_2).

```
@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just found it in the stylesheet before your answer.